# Alternate for replace() or replaceAll() methods

Tags: java, string, replace

We have a requirement where we have to replace a string. But we should not use replace() or replaceAll() methods. How can we achieve this in Java?

For example:

**First string**: Life is practical
(Here **Life** string has to be replaced with '**Everything in the world**')

**Expected Output**:
Everything in the world is practical

Comment: why cant you implement your own replace method?

Comment: go to String Class..and see the implementation of replace and replaceall methods... then you can Do it your own

Comment: No. Our requirement is not to use the replace() methods

Comment: @VishalSantharam how do I do that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one.

```
public class ReplaceTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "Life is practical";  //At first
    testReplace(str);

    str = "I have Life"; //At last
    testReplace(str);

    str = "I have Life, Life is beautiful"; //in the mid
    testReplace(str);


}

private static void testReplace(String str) {
    String[] strArr = str.split("Life");
    StringBuilder newStr = new StringBuilder(strArr[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < strArr.length; i++) {
        newStr.append("Everything").append(strArr[i]);
    }

    if (str.endsWith("Life")) {
        newStr.append("Everything");
    }
    System.out.println(newStr.toString());

}

}
```

OUTPUT:
Everything is practical
I have Everything
I have Everything, Everything is beautiful

Comment: If you got your answer, please tick the solution as accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**This will do..**

```
return firstString.substring(0,firstString.indexOf(strPrevString))+strNextString+firstString.substring(firstString.indexOf(strPrevString)+strPrevString.length(),firstString.length());
```

where `strPrevString`=Life is practical;

and `strNextString`=Everything in the world

Answer (score 0):

Modified From the Java Source code:

```
 public String customReplaceAll(String sourceString ,String regex, String replacement) 
     {      
       return Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(src).replaceAll(replacement);
     }
```

USAGE:

```
System.out.println(customReplaceAll("Hi da Hi","Hi","Bye"));
```

O/P:

```
Bye da Bye
```

Comment: Thanks ya its working. But in the above code also you are using replaceAll() method again??? I want something with only regular expression ??

Comment: That replace method id for Pattern not for String.